# registering event handlers in Chaplin application

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events, chaplinjs

In a Chaplin application I have a combination of a collection view and an item view, and I need clickable buttons at both collection level and item level. The collection is represented as a table, the items as rows. The buttons are simply <button id="id1">...</button> with an icon inside. All id's are unique.

Registering the event handler takes place in the initialize method of the view: @delegate 'click', 'button#id1', @handler.

At collection level this works (the event handlers show up in the Chrome debugging tool), but the event handlers at item level are not registered at all, according to the debugging tool. I've tried moving the delegate calls to the render method, but this gives the same result.

What am I doing wrong, and what I can do to register the events of the item views?

Answer (score 0):

After going through the source code a few times and some experimentation: you have to wait until the collection view is rendered (which implies that all item views are rendered and attached to the DOM), and then you register the event handlers of the collection view and the item views.